# Is their any methods to set set the linear gauge tickmarklables in steelseries jar?

Tags: java, swing

I'am using steelseries jar file for Linear gauge chart. In that i will not able to set the Tickmarklables normally. It was showing only 0 and 50 range labels in scale. I will try many method but it will not work

i want proper scale tickmarlabels. Please give me the linear gauge code by using steelseries jar

Comment: This seems to be the documentation: [Java swing component library "SteelSeries"](https://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-swing-component-library.html).  Quoting from the blog post: "The tickmarks could be modified by the properties "minValue" and "maxValue". You could also use negative values for "minValue".
If you would like to adjust the labels at the tickmarks you could define the period between the labled tickmarks by the property "tickLabelPeriod" (e.g. a value of 10 will label 0, 10, 20, 30 etc.).
To enable/disable the tickmarks completly use "tickMarksVisible".

Comment: please provide a linear gauge code  by using steelseries jar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.